# verify continuous segments in list

Tags: python, list

I want to verify if a condition of sequential segments is appearing in a list or not

An example:

I can have two options, either a list would be like this

```
[7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7 ....]
```

or

```
[......, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, ......]
```

What I want here
is that I want to go through the list and verify if I find 0's between 10's or 10's between 0's .. I return true

Note:

1- Whatever else inside the list is not important for me

2- The number of 0's or 10's is not fixed, they can change .. however, the most important manner, that if there are 0's there have to be 10's before or after .. or the other way around 0's before and after 10's

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean by "array"? What I see is a list. Or do you have a numpy array? This should be specified.

Comment: @Mr.T yes sorry .. it can be a list or np.array 
I am talking generally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating a small function that turns the lists into strings and runs a regex against it, You could tidy this up, or I could if you approve this concept

I'm not a regex, expert I'm sure there is another way to do this without using the `AttribeError` but this will work, someone can improve this, but it works.

```
import re

def finder(s):
    s = ''.join(str(s))
    match = re.search(r'0\,\s10,(\s10,)*\s0', s)
    try:
        if (match.group(0)):
            return True
    except AttributeError:
            pass

    match = re.search(r'10\,\s0,(\s0,)*\s10', s)
    try:
        if (match.group(0)):
            return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False

l1 = [7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7]
l2 = [10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10] 
l3 = [5, 5, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 8, 10, 0, 8, 9, 9, 5]

print(finder(l1))
print(finder(l2))
print(finder(l3))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow/sept$ python3.7 check.py
> True
> True
> False
> ```

Comment: and what about a case, that none of these conditions satisfies ? like an array with 10's and 7's for example and no 0's is available

Comment: it will return `False` if you look at the function if nothing matches it returns `False`

Comment: I passed this array `[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]`, and I got this error     `if (match.group(0)):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` I assume because there are no 0's here, right ?

Comment: You are correct, I'm going to account for that now

Comment: @MostafaHussein Updated

Comment: thanks .. I will try it and inform you back

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding you can do something like below.

First find the indexes of 0 ,10s then iterate over them to check if main list is having 0 or 10 in between them. Later check for True/False if some found elements it will return True else False will be returned.

```
from more_itertools import locate

l = [7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7]

# get the indexes of 0's and 10's in given list/array
zeros = list(locate(l, lambda x: x == 0))
tens = list(locate(l, lambda x: x == 10))

# check for each combination and return true/false in each time
find_10s = [(10 in (l[zeros[i]:zeros[i]+1])) for i in range(len(zeros))]
find_0s = [(0 in (l[tens[i]:tens[i]+1])) for i in range(len(tens))]

# this line is to check if anything found in above results 
print(any(find_10s) or any(find_0s)) #False
```